# How to calculate median and mode using Apache spark in java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

This page contains mean,max,variance etc but not median and mode.https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/mllib-statistics.html

I have used this code to parse data

```
JavaRDD<Vector> parseData = data .map(new Function<String, Vector>() { 
  /** * */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public Vector call(String line) {
    // del = " " String[] sArray = line.trim().split(delimiterFinal);
    double[] values = new double[sArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++) {
      if (columnsSet.contains(i)) {
         values[i] = Double.parseDouble(sArray[i]);
      }
    }
  return Vectors.dense(values);
}
```

Comment: afaik: you have to code it by yourself. but it's very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, agreed, you going to have to code them yourself (good exercise though ). The median for example is very simple, you can just sort and find the middle point (check median definition for details) and then you have two situations, one the split occurs exactly at one point (nvalues%%2=1) then thats the value, or second (nvalues%%2=0) then is the average of those two values.

Mode is even simpler, just the value that shows the most.

Comment: Computing exact median is simple but it can be prohibitively expensive on large datasets.